All homogeneous system of linear equations in n variables with det $A_{n\times n}\neq 0$ are equivalent
I was reading Hoffman and kunze(2nd edition) and on page number 5, Excercise 2, while showing the given two homogeneous system of linear equations are equivalent I realised if I have any homogeneous system of linear equations of order n with $det A \neq 0$, which means the matrix associated with it will have independent row vectors and I have n independent row vectors so it will span $\mathbb{R}^n$ with which I can write any vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a linear combination of these vectors and hence can write any other homogeneous system of linear equations with $det B \neq 0$  as a linear combination of the original system. Hence they will be equivalent by definition. The reason I am talking homogeneous system is so that I don't have to worry about the RHS of equal sign, which in any linear combination will be zero only
Can someone please help in writing a formal proof for this? Given if my trail of logic is correct then

What exactly is your notion of equivalence here? If it’s “same solution set”, then they are obviously equivalent because $A$ and $B$ are invertible. If you mean $A$ and $B$ are related by basis transformations, then they are equivalent if and only if they are similar.

@Pranay Definition: Two system of linear equations are equivalent if each equation in each system is a linear combination of the equation in the other system

Okay. Then I don’t see what this has to do with equations. What you are saying is essentially that the rows of $A$ are linear combinations of rows of $B$ and vice versa. This follows from the fact that both sets of rows form a basis as you said. I don’t know what more you want here.

@Pranay I just wrote my raw thoughts, I want a proper well written proof that's it

Yes yourself logic is correct
Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be the matrix representation of a homogenous system of linear equations, with $\det A \neq 0$
$\implies$ row vectors $\{(a_{ij})_{j=1}^n \}_{i=1}^n$ are linearly independent. Now we have $n$ linearly independent vectors of $\mathbb R^n$, and hence they will form a basis of $\mathbb R^n$
Now any other homogenous system of linear equations with $\det B \neq 0$, having matrix representation $B=(b_{ij})$ will also have independent row vectors $\{(b_{ij})_{j=1}^n \}_{i=1}^n$ and hence form basis of $\mathbb R^n$
Now by using the definition of equivalent matrix from your comments, I can write any row(row vector) of original system using linear combination of rows(row vectors) of another system and hence they are equivalent
$\therefore$ All homogenous system of linear equations in $n$ variables with $\det A_{n \times n} \neq 0$ are equivalent

One easy proof of this would be using Theorem $1$, from Hoffman and kunze($2^{\text{nd}}$ edition) page number $5$, which states equivalent systems of linear equations have exactly the same solutions:
Let,$\quad AX=0$
Since all the system of linear equations are homogeneous with a non-zero determinant,
$\implies A^{-1} \text{ exists}$
$\implies A^{-1}AX= A^{-1}O$
$\implies X=O$
$\therefore$ All systems will have trivial solution(i.e., same solution) and hence by Theorem $1$, they are equivalent.
